# Transposed pattern search

Tags: perl, awk

I have text file with format

```
  1   5.287  15.026   0.623 1 U   1.805E+05  0.000E+00 e 0   666   761   769 
  2   4.601  15.023   0.623 4 U   6.220E+04  0.000E+00 e 0     0     0     0 
  3   2.883  15.059   0.623 3 U   3.303E+05  0.000E+00 e 0   680   761   769 
  4   0.623  56.340   5.287 3 U   9.990E+04  0.000E+00 e 0   769   590   666
```

....

I want to identify lines where column 11 matches to column 13 and column 13 matches to column 11 of any other line (e.g. Line 1 and Line 4). I wish to add a comment at the end of both lines and print the entire file.

```
  1   5.287  15.026   0.623 1 U   1.805E+05  0.000E+00 e 0   666   761   769   #Line 4
  2   4.601  15.023   0.623 4 U   6.220E+04  0.000E+00 e 0     0     0     0 
  3   2.883  15.059   0.623 3 U   3.303E+05  0.000E+00 e 0   680   761   769 
  4   0.623  56.340   5.287 3 U   9.990E+04  0.000E+00 e 0   769   590   666   #Line 1
```

This is NMR spectroscopy data. You help is highly appreciated.
Thank you
-mandar

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show the code.  SO is not a "write the code for me" site.

Comment: @JimGarrison Sorry about that. I am from non-technical background. I was trying awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($11==$13 && $13==$11); print $0 "#Line" $1 }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %col11_13;

# read file
my @lines = map { chomp; [ split, $_] } <>; 

# prepare hash in the first pass
for my $i (0..@lines - 1) {
  push (@{$col11_13{$lines[$i][10]."|".$lines[$i][12]}}, $i + 1); 
}

# output in the second...
for my $i (0..@lines - 1) {
  # get the list of matching records, but filter out a self match
  my @s = grep { $_ != $i + 1 } @{$col11_13{$lines[$i][12]."|".$lines[$i][10]}};
  if (@s) {
    print $lines[$i][13], "# Line ", join(" ", @s) ,"\n";
  } else {
    print $lines[$i][13], "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: How to modify your code to run only on non-zero values of column 11 and 13. (e.g. how to overlook line 2 of my original example?). Thank you.

Comment: change the push like this: `push (@{$col11_13{$lines[$i][10]."|".$lines[$i][12]}}, $i + 1) if ($lines[$i][10] && $lines[$i][12]);`

Comment: What's the `grep` in your answer doing?  Looks like it's trying to prevent a line from matching itself, but it took me a moment to figure that out.  A comment might be useful there.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, yes that's exactly what I did. Updated, thanks.